# How do I convert several hundrets of point clouds (xyz.files) into meshes (obj-format) using meshlab server?

Tags: server, mesh, point-clouds, meshlab, xyz

I have about 200 point-cloud files (in the xyz-format) that I want to automativally convert into meshes (in the obj format). How do I write a batch-file for this task in the meshlab server? The meshes should be in a very good quality and there can't be any holes inside the mesh. In addition to that the mesh should look like the pointcloud and it can't have any aritifacts or problems with normals.

This link has a sample xyz-file in it. Maybe it helps to come up with a result to this question.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/128d1CNonGSn5AjmvS0jl49SFzrbtUE6K/view?usp=sharing

Thank you very much in advance for your help!!

Chris

Comment: Meshlabserver is discontinued, you should  try pymeshlab instead.

Comment: Also, forget about fully automatic conversion should produce such excelent results. The point to surface conversion is dependant of  factors as noise, density, oclussions, that makes very difficult building a mesh without user intervention.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I have seen that meshlabserver is discontinued...
But maybe you could give some sample code for a batchfile. I could just try how the same settings would work for every file. If some files turn out to be a little faulty, I could change the settings for those manually. But since I have over a 200 files to process, I woud like to at least try it with a batch-file. Using the meshlabserver with an older version of meshlab would be totally fine for my purposes. Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: It's impossible to reconstruct a mesh from only its points, but you can construct a mesh of their _convex hull_. If this is not what you want, you're already out of luck.